# Disabling "Save As" for video - iframe tag w/in Java script in a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I'm going to apologize ahead of time. I'm editing some code written by someone else and am not a PHP or Javascript programmer. The code embeds a video into a website. All I need to do is disable the ability to right click on the video and save it. The website is already password protected and I know there are other ways to save the video, but this will add just a little bit of protection.

I believe I just need to change something within the iframe tag?

Here's the script:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready( function() {

  video_field = 'video_url';
  desc_field = 'iframe_holder';

  // Get the video url
  video_url = $('input[name="' + video_field + '"]').val();

  // Get the last td in the descriptive field (where the iframe will be inserted)
  holder_td = $('#' + desc_field + '-tr td.labelrc:last');

  // Make a dummy iframe inserting the video_url as the source
  iframe = $('<iframe height="400" width="700" name="video" seamless="seamless" src="' + video_url + '">Your browser does not suppport iframes</iframe>');

  // Insert iframe into descriptive field
  iframe.appendTo(holder_td);
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: What is purpose of attempting to disable saving resources loaded at `document`?

Comment: Do you have control over the page that's loaded in the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pointless exercise, there's nothing to prevent the user from viewing the source of the page or inspecting the network requests using the dev tools or a web browser plugin.

If you insist, then the following JavaScript snippet will prevent a right click from performing any action.

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
```

Comment: _Note:_ That needs to be implemented on the page that gets included in the iframe. If you do it on the parent, it won't affect the iframe. And it's worth to point out that disabling right click on the whole page will just annoy the crap out of people...

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I understand there are other ways to save the video, but I'd like to at least prevent the easiest way. On which line do I insert this code?

Comment: The code works on the document so you could place it anywhere within a `$(document).ready( function() {` ...  `});` code block.

Comment: Yes! That did work, sort of. That disabled right clicking on the entire page but not within the iframe. I also had to change the iframe tag from: `'<iframe height=` to `'<video height=`